# Add a new Image to an action button

Tags: java, image, swt, package

I want to add a new Icon that is currently in the workspace of the project, concretly in "icons/launch.png", to a button in a eclipse project. The standard code is this:

```
action1.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
  getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));
```

This add the `IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK` to the button.

Does anyone know how to add a new Image to it?

Comment: @Shakedown isn't setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench() about SWT / GWT ...

Comment: as you see your question isn't answerable, fo better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), sure maybe for SWT is not required

Comment: @mKorbel: Ah you're right, my bad! I wanted to get it tagged with something UI-related so the right people would see it. Thanks for correcting the tags

Comment: What does _new image_ mean? Where does the image come from? Please show the code that you tried so far.